# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted

Tags: qgis

I got this error, RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QLineEdit has been deleted and 
this one RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type LeastCostPathAlgorithm has been deleted.

I think that is the reason that I cannot execute many tools such as Fill Sinks (Wang and Liu) but I am not sure. For example when I use the Fill Sink tool the parameter for Fill Sink is executed but the flow direction parameter and watershed basins are not.

I was trying to understand what is going wrong. So when I went in settings-options-scripts and chose Script Folder and I click OK I got those errors.

I think that some operations cannot be executed because there is problem with python but I am not sure if I am correct.

Do you know something about it? 
Is there a relationship in terms of the errors when I run the tools that I mention?
Do you know how can I fix it?

I use the last version of QGIS 3.10.1 'A Coruna', actually I downloaded the OSGeo4W Network.